# iOS Autocomplete UITEXTVIEW | Add autocomplete suggestions dynamically

Tags: ios, autocomplete, uitextview

I've been trying to implement an autocomplete UITEXTVIEW for my email app using this

```
https://github.com/hoteltonight/HTAutocompleteTextField
```

I would like to add the email addresses dynamically though. Is there any way to achieve the same. Because when I checked, the email addresses are initialised at start as given below.

```
HTEmailAutocompleteTextField.m

- (void)setupAutocompleteTextField
{
[super setupAutocompleteTextField];

// Default email domains to suggest
self.emailDomains = @[ @"gmail.com", @"yahoo.com"];

self.autocompleteDataSource = self;
}
```

The above method is called from `HTAutocompleteTextField.m`[`- (void)awakeFromNib`] as soon as the app is launched thereby not letting me to add email addresses dynamically.

Is there any work around because I get my email addresses later.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this from GitHub readme

```
HTAutocompleteTextField *textField = [[HTAutocompleteTextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,100,31)];
```

The data source is the brains of the autocomplete logic. If you just want to autocomplete email addresses, use HTAutocompleteManager from the example project as follows:

```
textField.autocompleteDataSource = [HTAutocompleteManager sharedManager];
textField.autocompleteType = HTAutocompleteTypeEmail;
```

Alternatively, you may wish to create your own data source class and user the autocompleteType property to differentiate between fields with different data types. A HTAutocompleteTextFields's data source must implement the following method, as part of the HTAutocompleteDataSource protocol.

-`(NSString *)textField:(HTAutocompleteTextField *)textField completionForPrefix:(NSString *)prefix ignoreCase:(BOOL)ignoreCase`